# Sendmail: Block email going to specific address [Centos]

Tags: centos, email, sendmail

We've inherited some systems with `CentOS` that are sending emails to people are no longer working for us. So, since there is no clue which app is sending these emails, I wanted to block them from the source, I have tried to block it from the access file in `/etc/mail/access` as following:

```
# Check the /usr/share/doc/sendmail/README.cf file for a description
# of the format of this file. (search for access_db in that file)
# The /usr/share/doc/sendmail/README.cf is part of the sendmail-doc
# package.
#
# by default we allow relaying from localhost...
Connect:localhost.localdomain           RELAY
Connect:localhost                       RELAY
Connect:127.0.0.1                       RELAY

To:address@gmail.com                    REJECT
```

After loading the new configs to `access.db`, still I can see email logs going to `address@gmail.com`

Any idea why this configurations did not help?

Thanks!

Comment: Does your `sendmail.mc` have this configured/uncommented? `FEATURE(\`access_db’)dnl`. `access.db` will not be ingested if that line is either commented or does not exist (or some variation of that field). Also, because you've edited `sendmail.mc` and/or access, you need to regenerate `/etc/mail/sendmail.cf` or have the db rebuilt: `cd /etc/mail` `make`, then restart sendmail.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIR blocking email to specific address via access table requires `FEATURE(access_db)` **and `FEATURE(blacklist_recipients)`** in `sendmail.mc`.
[ `sendmail.mc` must be recompiled into `sendmail.cf` and sendmail daemon restarted or HUped ]

See [`cf/README`](https://www.sendmail.org/%7Eca/email/doc8.12/cf/m4/features.html#blacklist_recipients) file in sendmail distribution.

Comment: I believe he wants to only block emails being sent out to specific addresses where `blacklist_recipients` is dealing with incoming e-mail. He likely just needs to check the `Feature(\`access_db')` flag is not commented out or excluded entirely and needs to regenerate and restart.

Comment: In default modern sendmail installations local sendmail daemon receives all messages via SMTP (even sent via sendmail command at localhost).